# SQL update query to get values by joining 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

Please help me to write update query for below. I am using SQL server 2014.

Requirement: Update Table C based on project Id, get corresponding  'Answer_weightage' values for corresponding project ID and from latest record. Table A 'Latest'= 'Yes' means it is a latest record. Based on 'Link_Id' Table A and B are linked. Table A and C are linked based on 'Project_Id'

**Table A:**

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>
Request Type | 
</th>
<th>Project ID  | </th>
<th>Latest |</th>
<th> Link_ID</th>
</tr>
<tr>
-----------------------------------------------
</tr>
<tr>
<td>

a 
</td>
<td>1000</td> <td>No</td> <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>b</td> <td>1005</td> <td>Yes </td>       <td>2</td>
<tr>
<td>123</td> <td>1000</td><td>Yes   </td>     <td>4</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>c </td><td>1005</td> <td>No</td> <td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Table B**

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>
Question</th> <th>Description</th> <th>Answer_weightage</th> <th>Link_ID
</th>

</tr>

<tr><td>
6 </td><td>Question6 </td><td>0</td> <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td> <td>Question2</td> <td>5</td> <td>4</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td> <td>Question3 </td><td>5</td> <td>4</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td> <td>Question4</td><td> 5</td> <td>4</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>5 </td><td>Question5 </td><td>2</td> <td>4</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td> <td>Question6 </td><td>2 </td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td> <td>Question7</td> <td>9 </td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td> <td>Question1 </td><td>5</td> <td>1</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td> <td>Question2 </td><td>9</td> <td>1</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>3 </td><td>Question3 </td><td>5</td><td> 1</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td> <td>Question4</td> <td>2 </td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td> <td>Question5</td> <td>5 </td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td> <td>Question6</td> <td>5 </td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td> <td>Question7</td> <td>2</td> <td>1</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td> <td>Question1</td> <td>2 </td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td> <td>Question2</td> <td>0 </td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>3 </td><td>Question3</td> <td>9 </td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td> <td>Question4 </td><td>9</td><td> 2</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>5 </td><td>Question5 </td><td>9</td><td> 2</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>7 </td><td>Question7</td> <td>5 </td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td> <td>Question1</td><td> 2</td> <td>4</td></tr>

</table>
```

**Table C:**

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>Project ID</th>
<th>Question1</th>
<th>Question2</th>
<th>Question3</th>
<th>Question4</th>
<th>Question5</th>
<th>Question6</th>
<th>Question7</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1000</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1005</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Desired Result (in Table C):**

```html
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Project ID</th>
    <th>Question1</th>
    <th>Question2</th>
    <th>Question3</th>
    <th>Question4</th>
    <th>Question5</th>
    <th>Question6</th>
    <th>Question7</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1005</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Do you have any `UPDATE` that you tested?

Comment: @RadimBača I am very new to writing sql queries.. This is what I wrote as of now :  update a
set a.[Question]=b.[Answer_weightage] where b.[Description]="Question1" where b.[link_id]=(select c.[link_id] from table c where c.[project_id]=a.[project_id] and a.[latest]='Yes'

Comment: Just cut and paste your formatted tables into a code block (indent 4 spaces, eg click on "{}" in the answer edit box toolbar), don't use a code snippet. Please clarify in your answer, not in comments. What have you tried? Please "show research effort" to avoid downvotes. Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to update question1 of Table C, set the value equal to Answer_weightage selected from B where b.Description = 'Question1' and linkId = (Link_Id from A where latest='YES' and has same projectId as C).

```
Update C set C.Question1 =
 (select Answer_weightage
    from B
    where Description='Question1' and Link_ID =
         (select Link_ID
            from A
            where A.ProjectID = C.ProjectID and Latest='Yes'))
```

Comment: For blocks (entire lines) of code indent 4 spaces (click on "{}"), don't use backticks.